# ¿Porque position absolute no me funciona?

Tags: html, css, div, icons, position

Tengo una calificación de estrellas, el problema es que la posición absoluta no me funciona  y no se cual puede ser su problema, y el otro problema es que las estrellas no se rellenan en el orden adecuado, es decir, cuando pase el mouse por la primera se rellene de un color, por la segunda se rellene y así hasta la ultima, para que quede cinco estrellas de media calificación algo similar a la calificación de Play Store, ya me resulto el problema de que no puedo visualizar las estrellas.

```css
.icon--star {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star {
  display: block;
  direction: rtl;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star i {
  color: #f5f509;
  font-size: 3.25rem;
  padding-right: 0.1875em;
}

.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star i:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f5f509;
}

.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star i .fa-star,
.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star:hover i {
  color: #c0c0c0;
}

.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star:hover i::before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  content: '\f005';
}

.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star i .fa-star-o:hover::before,
.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star i:hover ~ i::before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  content: '\f005';
  color: #f5f509;
}

.fa-star-o {
  overflow: clip;
}

i .fa-star-o:nth-child(10) {
  color: #e2943a;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 30;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS3/estilo-24-1.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="fichas--star">
    <div class="calificacion__star">
      <div class="icon--star">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-star fa-star-o"></i>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-star fa-star-o"></i>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-star fa-star-o"></i>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-star fa-star-o"></i>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-star fa-star-o"></i>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-star fa-star-o"></i>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-star fa-star-o"></i>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-star fa-star-o"></i>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-star fa-star-o"></i>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-star fa-star-o"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué notaste para que digas que la posición absoluta no te funcione?, ¿Cómo quieres que sean tus resultados esperados? Agrega más detalles sobre eso.

Answer (score 2):

espero poder ayudarte.

Para realizar lo que deseas no necesitas `position`, estas serían las únicas reglas CSS que necesitarías:

```css
/*
  Cambiamos la direccion de cualquiera
  de los contenedores de las estrellas.
*/

.fichas--star {
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.icon--star {
  display: flex;
}

.icon--star i {
  padding: .25rem;
}

/*
  Indicamos que a la estrella que se le
  haga hover y a las hermanas de esta en
  su elemento ::before le agrege el icono
  de la estrella rellena.
*/

.fa-star:hover::before,
.fa-star:hover ~ .fa-star::before {
  content: '\f005';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #f5f509;
}
```

```html
<!--
  Prueba con este CDN ya que el que tienes
  no esta funcionando correctamente.
-->

<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"
  integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w=="
  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="fichas--star">
  <div class="calificacion__star">
    <div class="icon--star">
      <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tambien puedes cambiar la direccion con:

```css
{
  /* direction: rtl; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Y funciona de la misma manera.

Answer (score 1):

Modifica tus siguientes clases:

```
.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star i .fa-star,
.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star:hover i {
  color: #c0c0c0;
}

.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star:hover i::before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  content: '\f005';
}
```

Por las siguientes:

```
.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star i .fa-star,
.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star:hover ~ i {
  color: #c0c0c0;
}

.fichas--star .calificacion__star .icon--star i:hover::before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  content: '\f005';
}
```

De esta forma, cuando pases el mouse sobre una estrella, se rellenará esa estrella junto con las estrellas anteriores, pero no las posteriores.

---

Otro problema que vi es que el CDN que estás usando es incorrecto, prueba con la última versión de [**Font Awesome.**](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome)

---

[**Código completo.**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/ZEjWmyG)